# Relations in the fundamental group of a surface

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups, geometric-group-theory

Let $\Sigma$ be a smooth oriented surface (possibly with boundary) and $G:=\pi_1(\Sigma)$ its fundamental group. Suppose that two nonzero elements $\alpha$, $\beta\in G$ satisfies $\alpha \beta = \beta^m \alpha^n$ holds for some $m,n\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then my claim is that we must have $m=n =1$.

By abelinization, we have $\alpha^{n-1} = \beta^{1-m}\in H^1(\Sigma)$ but I could not proceed more. I'll appreciate if someone suggests an idea or more general statements on fundamental groups of surfaces.

Comment: This isn't always true. The two generators $a,b$ of $\pi_1(K)$ for $K$ the Klein bottle satisfy $ab=b^{-1}a$, for example.

Comment: Hint: Apart from $\Sigma=T^2$, every 2-generated subgroup of $\pi_1(\Sigma)$ is free.

Comment: @Thorgott Thanks for a nice example, but I'm assuming the surface is oriented.

Comment: @MoisheKohan That's so nice property. Does it also hold for surfaces with boundaries? I failed to find a reference. Could you tell me where I can find one?

Comment: For surfaces with boundary it indeed holds, in fact *every* subgroup is free, because the entire group is free (and every subgroup of a free group is free).

Comment: I am not sure it is written anywhere, the point is that if $\Sigma$ has empty boundary and genus $\ge 2$ then a 2-generated subgroup has infinite index (try to prove it, this is where 2-generated is used) and, hence, is the fundamental group of a noncompact surface. But noncompact surfaces have fre fundamental groups.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you very much. I'll try it. It is indeed helpful.

Comment: @LeeMosher Oh, I missed that point. Thank you!

Comment: @MoisheKohan It is written in "On certain subgroups of the fundamental group of a
closed surface" by William Jaco, though I agree it's a good exercise first and foremost.